# Handsontable sort Dropdown items by date

Tags: handsontable

Is there an option to sort your dropdown items (col-type date) by date?

As seen in the image below the date-values are not really sorted by date since 12/1/2014 is not at first position. Hope this additional information helps to understand my question.

[example of dropdown date items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztZj8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled it and found an answer from Handsontable team.
Unfortunately, the answer is **you can't** without making a workaround directly in the core of their API.

> You’d need to get to the source list of the Filters plugin. That is not possible using our official API.

[Reference](https://forum.handsontable.com/t/changing-order-of-filter-by-value-data/3260)